# Azure Function authentication with scopes / roles

Tags: spring, azure, function, authentication, scope

I have azure function which serces as an API for a frontend app. In the function I am receiving a request together with access token which contains a defined in Azure Portal scope: `"scp": "samplescope",`

I have app registration, I have Authentication provider set and I indeed get 401 when I request without auth token.

However how to add another authentication level in the app itself? I use spring-boot as a main framework and I would like to use something like `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SCOPE_samplescope')")`, but it is not possible for azure function (they are not @Controller / @GetMapping) and spring says
`org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext`

So my question is there an easy way to manage authentication on scope level? In the future the backend (function app) will serve for different UIs (possibly with different functions) and there should be some access control. For now I can't distinguish who calls the function.